# how to pass two values for a key in map without overwriting

Tags: apex

```
public static Map<String, map<string,string>> retrieveCategoryCodes(){
    Map<String, map<string,string>> seasonObjMap = new Map<String, map<string,string>>();
    for(CM_Kalido_Reference_Data__c seasonObj : [SELECT Id, CM_Category_Value__c, CM_Category_Type__c, CM_Category_Code__c FROM CM_Kalido_Reference_Data__c]){
    seasonObjMap.put(seasonObj.CM_Category_Type__c, new map<string,string>{seasonObj.CM_Category_Value__c=>seasonObj.CM_Category_Code__c});    
    system.debug('@@seasonObjMap'+seasonObjMap);
    }
    system.debug('seasonObjMap'+seasonObjMap);
    return seasonObjMap;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to pass category code with different category values and category codes but map is storing only last value from iteration

Comment: That's how maps work. There can only be one value for each key in a map. The last map value put to the map is the one that "wins" by overwriting the previous value for the key. If you know your values will be unique, you may want to reverse your mapping.

Comment: ya i'm trying to get the map output as category type A can have category value B and Category code as 2 for one record  similarly  category type A can have category value c and Category code as 2 for other record can we build a map for such scenario which doesnot over ride each ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the outer map already has a value, and if so, use the existing map. Generically, you can write it like this:

```
public static Map<String, map<string,string>> retrieveCategoryCodes(){
    Map<String, map<string,string>> seasonObjMap = new Map<String, map<string,string>>();
    for(CM_Kalido_Reference_Data__c seasonObj : [SELECT Id, CM_Category_Value__c, CM_Category_Type__c, CM_Category_Code__c FROM CM_Kalido_Reference_Data__c]){
      if(seasonObjMap.containsKey(seasonObj.CM_Category_Type__c)) {
        seasonObjMap.get(seasonObj.CM_Category_Type__c).put(seasonObj.CM_Category_Value__c, seasonObj.CM_Category_Code__c);
      } else {
        seasonObjMap.put(seasonObj.CM_Category_Type__c, new map<string,string>{seasonObj.CM_Category_Value__c=>seasonObj.CM_Category_Code__c});
      }
    }
    return seasonObjMap;
}
```